# sfml animation of explosion after mouseclick

Tags: c++, animation, sfml

I need your piece of advice. I'm using SFML and I need to play animation from the spritesheet(f.e. 64 frames and 40px width/height of each frame) after mouseclick event. The only solution I've come to is:

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Mouse::Left) {
                    float frame = 0;
                    float frameCount = 64;
                    float animSpeed = 0.005;
                    while (frame < frameCount) {
                        spriteAnimation->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(int(frame)*w, 0, w, w));
                        frame += animSpeed;
                        window->draw(rect); // clear the area of displaying animation
                        window->draw(*spriteAnimation);
                        window->display();

                    }
                    ...
```

But calling window->display() so many times is really not good;
Can you suggest better variants?

Comment: call window->display() at the end of the game loop its the best

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jamming all of your code for the animation into the event block you should spread it out.

Your design here is very inflexible in that if you ever want to display anything other than an animation you are going to have to call `window->display()` *again* outside of your event loop.

Generally in SFML your game loop proceeds similarly to as follows:

```
initialize();
while(running)
{
    checkEvents();
    clear();
    update();
    display();
}
```

Instead of performing all of the calculations and displaying for your animation inside the event's `if` statement you should set a bool or call a `doAnimation()` function of some sort.  I've written a rough example below:

```
bool doAnimation = 0;
//declare frame, framespeed, etc
if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) 
{
    if (event.key.code == sf::Mouse::Left) 
    {
        doAnimation = true; 
        //reset frame, framespeed, etc         
    }
}
clear();
if(doAnimation)
{
    sprite->setTexture(...);
    if(frame == endFrame)
    {
        doAnimation = 0;   
    }
    drawSprite();
}
window->display();
```

There are tons of ways to solve your problem.  My example is less flexible than I would think is ideal but depending on the needs of your program it may work fine.  If you wanted to take the next step moving the animation into a class of some sort would make your life a lot easier in the long run.